# unified icons' backgrounds set

Tags: android, icons

I have little to no knowledge in Android development. I'm trying to make an icon pack that will put a single color background square on all apps.

can you please put me in the right direction?

Comment: `icon pack`  What does this mean?  Are you talking about launcher themes?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. I want to make a launcher theme (icon pack) that does one thing only, that's stated in the question.